# Bundle d.ts files into single file from DefinitelyTyped repo [@types/lodash]

Tags: lodash, definitelytyped

maybe a stupid question but I googled, and I didn't find the solution.

I have a legacy application(it doesn't use npn), and I need upgrade version of Lodash(from 3.x -> 4.x), And I cant find a bundled index.d.ts with type definitions for version 4. Version 3 has this useful bundled index.d.ts file [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/v3/index.d.ts)

But version 4 doesn't. How can I bundle d.ts files into one like in version 3?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/index.d.ts is the latest version (v4.14.108 as of the time of this post). You should be able to go back in the Git history to get all of the previous versions of it too, if you need the types for a specific version of Lodash v4.x.x

Comment: Thank you for you comment, but this index.d.ts is only refence to other d.ts files. I would like to single file with all types. Like in version 3.